# R Plotly how to use both position dodge and format hover text

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I want to create a plotly object that is 1.) position dodged on the x-axis and 2.) has formatted text the way I want it. I am able to fulfil each condition separately but am unable to do them both at the same time.

Here I have a plotly plot that is properly position dodged

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = runif(8, 5, 10),
  cat = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
)

p <- ggplot(df, groups = cat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = cat),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.3))

ggplotly(p)
```

And here I have a plotly plot with formatted hover text

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~x, 
        y = ~y, 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'markers',
        color = ~cat,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste('</br> X is ', x,
                      '</br> Y is ', y,
                      '</br> Cat is ', cat
        )
)
```

How can I combine these two ideas so that I have a plot that is position dodged and also with manually formatted hover text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your customized hover text via the `text` "aesthetic" and adding argument `tooltip="text"` to your call of `ggplotly`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = runif(8, 5, 10),
  cat = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
)

p <- ggplot(df, groups = cat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = cat, 
                 text = paste('</br> X is ', x, '</br> Y is ', y, '</br> Cat is ', cat)), 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.3))

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```